# How to substract one month in SYSDATE() in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My Database date is like 
"2013-07-09" that is 9th August.
SYSDATE() is "2013-08-09" that is also 9th August.
When i am going to take data into database using this SYSDATE() in takes 08 which is   month number is September.
So I want to subtract one month in SYSDATE().

Comment: `2013-07-09` is Aug 9 in the database? Why are you storing 1 less than the month number, and how are you storing it? A `DATE`? `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson:- i am storing it into the DateFormat

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson:- i mean in date.

Comment: That means that when you use (month-1) as month, you can't even store March 31 in the database...? '2013-02-31' won't even insert.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson:- It will insert. The main difference between SYSDATE() and date in mysql is that for SYSDATE() 8 is an August and for date is September. So i have to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you create a repeatable example of them returning values with differing month value? [I can't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6e2/1).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson:- i have 47,46 values in database stored as comma seperated in string. I want to check for the 46 value in this comma separated string. So how can i find the values for the 46 in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange is going on in your database.  It looks to me like the system time is set incorrectly, or something else is wrong.

"2013-07-09" is the ninth of July, 2013.  "yyyy-mm-dd" is the layout.
"2013-08-09" is the ninth of August, 2013.

There is no valid and correctly set up MySQL instance where "2013-07-09" means the ninth of August or vice versa.  Month "08" has never meant September. So, if your dates have any significance, you need to get to the bottom of this quickly.  DBMS systems loaded with tons of data with fouled up dates are an ongoing nightmare: I know this from hard experience.

If you need the date one month before whatever_date, use this MySQL expression.

```
DATE_SUB(whatever_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

There's something else you need to know: `NOW()` means the same thing as `SYSDATE()` with a small distinction: `NOW()` is evaluated just once during the execution of each query, whereas `SYSDATE()` is re-evaluated whenever the database engine wants to.  Most programmers consider `NOW()` to be a better choice because it's deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

DATE_SUB(sysdate(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  will give you sysdate minus one month.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: I want to do this for the SYSDATE, not for the now().